# Give context-free grammars that generate the following languages.

Tags: computer-science

1. L1={a^n b^2n c^m |n,m>0}
2. L2 = {a^3n b^2n | n ≥ 0}, the alphabet is ∑={a,b}
3. L3 = {a^i b^j c^k | i, j, k ≥ 0 and i+j <= k},
   the alphabet is ∑={a,b,c}

Comment: Use mathjax, please.